# Hybris : How to import using impex?

Tags: java, spring, import, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I am trying to import a product using impex but the script is not working I don't understand why. This is my script:

```
insert TaxRow ; &Item ; catalogVersion(catalog(id),version) ; creationtime[forceWrite=true,dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss] ; currency(isocode) ; endTime[dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss] ; modifiedtime[dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss] ; owner(&Item)[allownull=true] ; pg(code,itemtype(code))     ; product(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; productId[forceWrite=true] ; productMatchQualifier ; startTime[dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss] ; tax(code)[allownull=true,forceWrite=true] ; ug(code,itemtype(code)) ; user(uid) ; userMatchQualifier ; value
              ; Item0 ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged         ; 18.02.2019 04:00:18                                          ;                   ;                                         ; 18.02.2019 04:00:18                          ;                              ; standard:ProductTaxGroup    ;                                                   ;                            ; 8 796 129 198 171     ;                                           ; standard                                  ;                         ;           ; 0                  ;      
              ; Item1 ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged         ; 30.05.2017 03:25:52                                          ;                   ;                                         ; 30.05.2017 03:25:52                          ;                              ; eu-vat-full:ProductTaxGroup ;                                                   ;                            ; 8 796 129 362 011     ;                                           ; uk-vat-full                               ; uk-taxes:UserTaxGroup   ;           ; 8 796 129 034 331  ;      
              ; Item2 ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged         ; 30.05.2017 03:25:52                                          ;                   ;                                         ; 30.05.2017 03:25:52                          ;                              ; eu-vat-half:ProductTaxGroup ;                                                   ;                            ; 8 796 129 427 547     ;                                           ; de-vat-half                               ; de-taxes:UserTaxGroup   ;           ; 8 796 129 132 635  ;      
              ; Item3 ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged         ; 30.05.2017 03:25:52                                          ;                   ;                                         ; 30.05.2017 03:25:52                          ;                              ; eu-vat-full:ProductTaxGroup ;                                                   ;                            ; 8 796 129 362 011     ;                                           ; de-vat-full                               ; de-taxes:UserTaxGroup   ;           ; 8 796 129 132 635  ;      
              ; Item4 ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged         ; 30.05.2017 03:25:52                                          ;                   ;                                         ; 30.05.2017 03:25:52                          ;                              ; eu-vat-half:ProductTaxGroup ;                                                   ;                            ; 8 796 129 427 547     ;                                           ; uk-vat-half                               ; uk-taxes:UserTaxGroup   ;           ; 8 796 129 034 331  ;      
              ; Item5 ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged         ; 29.05.2017 03:34:46                                          ;                   ;                                         ; 29.05.2017 03:34:46                          ;                              ; specific:ProductTaxGroup    ;                                                   ;                            ; 8 796 129 263 707     ;                                           ; specific                                  ;                         ;           ; 0                  ;      
              ; Item6 ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged         ; 29.05.2017 03:34:46                                          ;                   ;                                         ; 29.05.2017 03:34:46                          ;                              ; zero:ProductTaxGroup        ;                                                   ;                            ; 8 796 129 230 939     ;                                           ; zero                                      ;                         ;           ; 0                  ;      
              ; Item7 ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged         ; 29.05.2017 03:34:46                                          ;                   ;                                         ; 29.05.2017 03:34:46                          ;                              ; jp-vat-full:ProductTaxGroup ;                                                   ;                            ; 8 796 129 394 779     ;                                           ; jp-vat-full                               ; jp-taxes:UserTaxGroup   ;           ; 8 796 129 099 867  ;      



insert_update Product ; &Item ; Europe1PriceFactory_PDG(code,itemtype(code)) ; Europe1PriceFactory_PPG(code,itemtype(code)) ; Europe1PriceFactory_PTG(code,itemtype(code)) ; activeProductReview ; approvalStatus(code,itemtype(code))[allownull=true] ; articleStatus[lang=en] ; articleStatus[lang=fr] ; baseNotes[lang=en] ; baseNotes[lang=fr] ; bestRated ; bestSeller[allownull=true] ; bestViewed[allownull=true] ; buyerIDS(key(code,itemtype(code))) ; catalog(id)[allownull=true] ; catalogVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true,allownull=true] ; code[unique=true,allownull=true] ; contentUnit(code) ; contentUnitSize ; creationtime[forceWrite=false,dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss] ; customPageTitle ; data_sheet(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; defaultSku(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; deliveryTime ; description[lang=en] ; description[lang=fr] ; detail(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; discountable[allownull=true] ; doNotOverrideApprovalStatus ; doNotOverwriteBestSeller ; doNotOverwriteNewProduct ; ean ; endLineNumber ; erpGroupBuyer ; erpGroupSupplier ; erpName[lang=en] ; erpName[lang=fr]             ; erpShortDescription[lang=en] ; erpShortDescription[lang=fr] ; erpStatus(code,itemtype(code)) ; europe1Discounts(&Item) ; europe1Prices(&Item) ; europe1Taxes(&Item) ; exclusiveBrand(code,itemtype(code)) ; exportToMakeUp ; extraZoomDisabled ; feedType(code,itemtype(code)) ; formulation[lang=en] ; formulation[lang=fr] ; galleryImages(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),qualifier) ; gender(code,itemtype(code)) ; generalPromotionText[lang=en] ; generalPromotionText[lang=fr] ; generalPromotion[allownull=true] ; giveAway ; heartNotes[lang=en] ; heartNotes[lang=fr] ; informativePrice1 ; informativePrice2 ; informativePrice3 ; informativePrice4 ; informativeText1[lang=en] ; informativeText1[lang=fr] ; informativeText2[lang=en] ; informativeText2[lang=fr] ; informativeText3[lang=en] ; informativeText3[lang=fr] ; ingredients[lang=en] ; ingredients[lang=fr] ; isAvaliableInMultipleShades ; logo(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; manufacturerAID ; manufacturerName ; manufacturerTypeDescription[lang=en] ; manufacturerTypeDescription[lang=fr] ; markDownMemPrice(&Item) ; markDownPrice(&Item) ; marketingClass(code,itemtype(code)) ; masterBrandRef(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; maxOrderQuantity ; minOrderQuantity ; modifiedtime[dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss] ; mrnDepartmentCode ; mrnFeatures[lang=en] ; mrnFeatures[lang=fr] ; mrnFinal ; mrnPrdVatCode ; mrnTipsAdviceHtml[lang=en] ; mrnTipsAdviceHtml[lang=fr] ; name[lang=en] ; name[lang=fr] ; newProduct[allownull=true] ; normal(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; numberContentUnits ; offlineDate[dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss] ; olfactives[lang=en] ; olfactives[lang=fr] ; onlineDate[dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss] ; order ; orderQuantityInterval ; others(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; owner(&Item)[allownull=true] ; packType[lang=en] ; packType[lang=fr] ; pharmacyInfo[lang=en] ; pharmacyInfo[lang=fr] ; picture(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; prdVatCode ; priceQuantity ; productOrderLimit(&Item) ; prohibitMemberPoints ; rangeName ; ranking ; recyclingInfo[lang=en] ; recyclingInfo[lang=fr] ; remarks[lang=en] ; remarks[lang=fr] ; segment[lang=en] ; segment[lang=fr] ; seoDescription[lang=en] ; seoDescription[lang=fr] ; sequenceId ; shippingInfo[lang=en] ; shippingInfo[lang=fr] ; shortDescription[lang=en] ; shortDescription[lang=fr] ; showPdpContentHubArticles ; showReserveAndCollectButton ; showVPProms ; specialTreatmentClasses() ; startLineNumber ; storageCondition[lang=en] ; storageCondition[lang=fr] ; storage[lang=en] ; storage[lang=fr] ; summary[lang=en] ; summary[lang=fr] ; supplier(code) ; supplierAlternativeAID ; thumbnail(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; thumbnails(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; topNotes[lang=en] ; topNotes[lang=fr] ; unit(code) ; uses[lang=en] ; uses[lang=fr] ; vOpeningBusinessRule(&Item) ; vSortingBusinessRule(&Item) ; variantType(code)        ; variants(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code) ; volume ; warnings[lang=en] ; warnings[lang=fr] ; webExclusive ; weight ; xmlcontent ; zoomDisabled
                      ; Item2 ;                                              ;                                              ; standard:ProductTaxGroup                     ; true                ; load:ArticleApprovalStatus                          ;                        ;                        ;                    ;                    ; 0         ; false                      ; false                      ;                                    ; hybrisProductCatalog        ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged                                     ; BP_101628163                     ;                   ;                 ; 13.02.2019 09:08:53                                           ;                 ;                                                      ;                                                      ;              ;                      ;                      ;                                                  ; false                        ; false                       ; false                    ; false                    ;     ;               ;               ;                  ;                  ; DEMO MELLE COUTUR.EDP90ML VP ;                              ; DEMO MELLE COUTUR.ED         ; Available:IgcErpStatusCode     ;                         ;                      ; Item0,Item1         ; N:IgcBrandTypeName                  ; false          ; false             ; IS21MD:ProductfeedType        ;                      ;                      ;                                                              ; FEMME:ProductGender         ;                               ;                               ; false                            ; false    ;                     ;                     ;                   ;                   ;                   ;                   ;                           ;                           ;                           ;                           ;                           ;                           ;                      ;                      ; false                       ;                                                ;                 ;                  ;                                      ;                                      ;                         ;                      ; A:MarketingClass                    ;                                                          ;                  ;                  ; 13.02.2019 09:08:56                          ;                   ;                      ;                      ; false    ;               ;                            ;                            ;               ;               ; false                      ;                                                  ;                    ;                                             ;                     ;                     ;                                            ;       ;                       ;                                                  ;                              ;                   ;                   ;                       ;                       ;                                                   ;            ; 1             ;                          ; false                ;           ;         ;                        ;                        ;                  ;                  ;                  ;                  ;                         ;                         ;            ;                       ;                       ;                           ;                           ; false                     ; true                        ; false       ;                           ;                 ;                           ;                           ;                  ;                  ;                  ;                  ; 1364900101     ;                        ;                                                     ;                                                      ;                   ;                   ; EACH       ;               ;               ;                             ;                             ; MrnGenericVariantProduct ;                                                    ;        ;                   ;                   ;              ; 328    ;            ; false
```

Here what it's mentioning at hac:

```
insert_update Product;&Item;Europe1PriceFactory_PDG(code,itemtype(code));Europe1PriceFactory_PPG(code,itemtype(code));Europe1PriceFactory_PTG(code,itemtype(code));activeProductReview;approvalStatus(code,itemtype(code))[allownull=true];articleStatus[lang=en];articleStatus[lang=fr];baseNotes[lang=en];baseNotes[lang=fr];bestRated;bestSeller[allownull=true];bestViewed[allownull=true];buyerIDS(key(code,itemtype(code)));catalog(id)[allownull=true];catalogVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true,allownull=true];code[unique=true,allownull=true];contentUnit(code);contentUnitSize;creationtime[forceWrite=false,dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss];customPageTitle;data_sheet(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);defaultSku(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);deliveryTime;description[lang=en];description[lang=fr];detail(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);discountable[allownull=true];doNotOverrideApprovalStatus;doNotOverwriteBestSeller;doNotOverwriteNewProduct;ean;endLineNumber;erpGroupBuyer;erpGroupSupplier;erpName[lang=en];erpName[lang=fr];erpShortDescription[lang=en];erpShortDescription[lang=fr];erpStatus(code,itemtype(code));europe1Discounts(&Item);europe1Prices(&Item);europe1Taxes(&Item);exclusiveBrand(code,itemtype(code));exportToMakeUp;extraZoomDisabled;feedType(code,itemtype(code));formulation[lang=en];formulation[lang=fr];galleryImages(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),qualifier);gender(code,itemtype(code));generalPromotionText[lang=en];generalPromotionText[lang=fr];generalPromotion[allownull=true];giveAway;heartNotes[lang=en];heartNotes[lang=fr];informativePrice1;informativePrice2;informativePrice3;informativePrice4;informativeText1[lang=en];informativeText1[lang=fr];informativeText2[lang=en];informativeText2[lang=fr];informativeText3[lang=en];informativeText3[lang=fr];ingredients[lang=en];ingredients[lang=fr];isAvaliableInMultipleShades;logo(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);manufacturerAID;manufacturerName;manufacturerTypeDescription[lang=en];manufacturerTypeDescription[lang=fr];markDownMemPrice(&Item);markDownPrice(&Item);marketingClass(code,itemtype(code));masterBrandRef(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);maxOrderQuantity;minOrderQuantity;modifiedtime[dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss];mrnDepartmentCode;mrnFeatures[lang=en];mrnFeatures[lang=fr];mrnFinal;mrnPrdVatCode;mrnTipsAdviceHtml[lang=en];mrnTipsAdviceHtml[lang=fr];name[lang=en];name[lang=fr];newProduct[allownull=true];normal(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);numberContentUnits;offlineDate[dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss];olfactives[lang=en];olfactives[lang=fr];onlineDate[dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss];order;orderQuantityInterval;others(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);owner(&Item)[allownull=true];packType[lang=en];packType[lang=fr];pharmacyInfo[lang=en];pharmacyInfo[lang=fr];picture(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);prdVatCode;priceQuantity;productOrderLimit(&Item);prohibitMemberPoints;rangeName;ranking;recyclingInfo[lang=en];recyclingInfo[lang=fr];remarks[lang=en];remarks[lang=fr];segment[lang=en];segment[lang=fr];seoDescription[lang=en];seoDescription[lang=fr];sequenceId;shippingInfo[lang=en];shippingInfo[lang=fr];shortDescription[lang=en];shortDescription[lang=fr];showPdpContentHubArticles;showReserveAndCollectButton;showVPProms;specialTreatmentClasses();startLineNumber;storageCondition[lang=en];storageCondition[lang=fr];storage[lang=en];storage[lang=fr];summary[lang=en];summary[lang=fr];supplier(code);supplierAlternativeAID;thumbnail(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);thumbnails(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);topNotes[lang=en];topNotes[lang=fr];unit(code);uses[lang=en];uses[lang=fr];vOpeningBusinessRule(&Item);vSortingBusinessRule(&Item);variantType(code);variants(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code);volume;warnings[lang=en];warnings[lang=fr];webExclusive;weight;xmlcontent;zoomDisabled
,,,;Item2;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>standard:ProductTaxGroup;<ignore>true;<ignore>load:ArticleApprovalStatus;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>0;<ignore>false;<ignore>false;<ignore>;<ignore>hybrisProductCatalog;<ignore>hybrisProductCatalog:Staged;<ignore>BP_101628163;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>13.02.2019 09:08:53;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>false;<ignore>false;<ignore>false;<ignore>false;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>DEMO MELLE COUTUR.EDP90ML VP;<ignore>;<ignore>DEMO MELLE COUTUR.ED;<ignore>Available:IgcErpStatusCode;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>Item0,Item1;<ignore>N:IgcBrandTypeName;<ignore>false;<ignore>false;<ignore>IS21MD:ProductfeedType;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>FEMME:ProductGender;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>false;<ignore>false;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>false;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>A:MarketingClass;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>13.02.2019 09:08:56;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>false;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>false;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>1;<ignore>;<ignore>false;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>false;<ignore>true;<ignore>false;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>1364900101;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>EACH;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>MrnGenericVariantProduct;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>;<ignore>328;<ignore>;<ignore>false


21.02.2019 14:33:27: ERROR: Can not resolve any more lines ... Aborting further passes (at pass 2). Finally could not import 1 lines!
```

And what at console:

```
    WARN  [impex result worker [cj:000002BR]] (000002BC) [ImpExImportReader] line 3 at main script: dumped unresolved line ValueLine[,line 3 at main script,null,HeaderDescriptor[line 2 at main script, insert_update, Product, {}, [&Item, Europe1PriceFactory_PDG, Europe1PriceFactory_PPG, Europe1PriceFactory_PTG, activeProductReview, approvalStatus, articleStatus, articleStatus, baseNotes, baseNotes, bestRated, bestSeller, bestViewed, buyerIDS, catalog, catalogVersion, code, contentUnit, contentUnitSize, creationtime, customPageTitle, data_sheet, defaultSku, deliveryTime, description, description, detail, discountable, doNotOverrideApprovalStatus, doNotOverwriteBestSeller, doNotOverwriteNewProduct, ean, endLineNumber, erpGroupBuyer, erpGroupSupplier, erpName, erpName, erpShortDescription, erpShor
    tDescription, erpStatus, europe1Discounts, europe1Prices, europe1Taxes, exclusiveBrand, exportToMakeUp, extraZoomDisabled, feedType, formulation, formulation, galleryImages, gender, generalPromotionText, generalPromotionText, generalPromotion, giveAway, heartNotes, heartNotes, informativePrice1, informativePrice2, informativePrice3, informativePrice4, informativeText1, informativeText1, informativeText2, informativeText2, informativeText3, informativeText3, ingredients, ingredients, isAvaliableInMultipleShades, logo, manufacturerAID, manufacturerName, manufacturerTypeDescription, manufacturerTypeDescription, markDownMemPrice, markDownPrice, marketingClass, masterBrandRef, maxOrderQuantity, minOrderQuantity, modifiedtime, mrnDepartmentCode, mrnFeatures, mrnFeatures, mrnFinal, mrnPrdVatCode,
     mrnTipsAdviceHtml, mrnTipsAdviceHtml, name, name, newProduct, normal, numberContentUnits, offlineDate, olfactives, olfactives, onlineDate, order, orderQuantityInterval, others, owner, packType, packType, pharmacyInfo, pharmacyInfo, picture, prdVatCode, priceQuantity, productOrderLimit, prohibitMemberPoints, rangeName, ranking, recyclingInfo, recyclingInfo, remarks, remarks, segment, segment, seoDescription, seoDescription, sequenceId, shippingInfo, shippingInfo, shortDescription, shortDescription, showPdpContentHubArticles, showReserveAndCollectButton, showVPProms, specialTreatmentClasses, startLineNumber, storageCondition, storageCondition, storage, storage, summary, summary, supplier, supplierAlternativeAID, thumbnail, thumbnails, topNotes, topNotes, unit, uses, uses, vOpeningBusinessRu
    le, vSortingBusinessRule, variantType, variants, volume, warnings, warnings, webExclusive, weight, xmlcontent, zoomDisabled] ],{1=ValueEntry('Item2'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=false), 2=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 3=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 4=ValueEntry('<ignore>standard:ProductTaxGroup'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 5=ValueEntry('<ignore>true'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 6=ValueEntry('<ignore>load:ArticleApprovalStatus'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 7=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 8=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 9=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 10=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 11=ValueEntry('<ignore>0'=nul
    l,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 12=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 13=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 14=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 15=ValueEntry('<ignore>hybrisProductCatalog'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 16=ValueEntry('<ignore>hybrisProductCatalog:Staged'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 17=ValueEntry('<ignore>BP_101628163'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 18=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 19=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 20=ValueEntry('13.02.2019 09:08:53'=Wed Feb 13 09:08:53 CET 2019,unresolved=false,ignore=false), 21=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 22=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 23
    =ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 24=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 25=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 26=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 27=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 28=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 29=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 30=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 31=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 32=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 33=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 34=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 35=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 36
    =ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 37=ValueEntry('<ignore>DEMO MELLE COUTUR.EDP90ML VP'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 38=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 39=ValueEntry('<ignore>DEMO MELLE COUTUR.ED'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 40=ValueEntry('<ignore>Available:IgcErpStatusCode'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 41=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 42=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 43=ValueEntry('<ignore>Item0,Item1'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 44=ValueEntry('<ignore>N:IgcBrandTypeName'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 45=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 46=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 47=ValueEntry('<ignore>IS21MD
    :ProductfeedType'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 48=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 49=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 50=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 51=ValueEntry('<ignore>FEMME:ProductGender'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 52=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 53=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 54=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 55=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 56=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 57=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 58=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 59=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true)
    , 60=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 61=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 62=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 63=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 64=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 65=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 66=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 67=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 68=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 69=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 70=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 71=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 72=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 73=ValueEntry
    ('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 74=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 75=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 76=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 77=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 78=ValueEntry('<ignore>A:MarketingClass'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 79=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 80=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 81=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 82=ValueEntry('<ignore>13.02.2019 09:08:56'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 83=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 84=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 85=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true)
    , 86=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 87=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 88=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 89=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 90=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 91=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 149=ValueEntry('<ignore>MrnGenericVariantProduct'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 150=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null
    ,ignore=true), 
------------------------------------
151=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 152=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 153=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 154=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 155=ValueEntry('<ignore>328'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 156=ValueEntry('<ignore>'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true), 157=ValueEntry('<ignore>false'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=true)}]
    INFO  [impex result worker [cj:000002BR]] (000002BC) [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex result worker [cj:000002BR] to the pool
    INFO  [impex reader worker [cj:000002BR]] (000002BC) [ImpExWorker] Returning worker impex reader worker [cj:000002BR] to the pool
    INFO  [hybrisHTTP20] (000002BR) [Importer] Finished 2 pass in 0d 00h:00m:00s:025ms - processed: 1, dumped: 1 (last pass: 1)
    WARN  [hybrisHTTP20] (000002BR) [Importer] Import aborted after 0d 00h:00m:00s:334ms
    ERROR [hybrisHTTP20] (000002BR) [ImpExImportJob] Can not resolve any more lines ... Aborting further passes (at pass 2). Finally could not import 1 lines!
    ERROR [hybrisHTTP20] [DefaultImportService] Import has caused an error, see logs of cronjob with code=000002BR for further details
```

Can someone please exmplain what's the issue. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried importing a subset of the attributes to narrow down the error? Looks like a export you made previously, is that right? Is there another exception in the logs?

Comment: @JohannesNolte what do you mean by "importing a subset of the attributes" sorry I did'nt get it, Can you please eloborate. The export seems to me right but I'm not sure. No there is just just this in logs. And sorry I'm new to hybris so all this is very confusing for me.

Comment: BTW I've generated the script of export from hmc. Actually I want to export producrs from one enviroment and to import to the another

Answer (score 6):

Impex scripts consists of two parts:

1. header
2. data

Those two can occur multiple times in an impex file.

---

**Header**

**Operation**: What to do with the following data: There are the following options:

- INSERT: Create new Items
- INSERT_UPDATE: Create new Items or update existing ones
- UPDATE: Update existing items
- REMOVE: Remove existing items

**Itemtype**: What type of items you want to edit (Product, Category, User...)

**Attributes** All attributes you want to edit separated by semicolons.

---

The format for the header looks like this:

```
OPERATION ITEMTYPE;ATTRIUTE1;ATTRIBUTE2;
```

With this example that would be:

```
INSERT Address ; firstname ; lastname ;
```

That would mean that you try to create a new item of type address with the attributes firstname and lastname.

---

**Data**

After the header the data follows. For every attribute in the header you can add data. Leave the first entry empty (start with a semicolon). Then add the value for each attribute respecting the order of the attributes in the header.

Format:

```
;value for attribute1;value for attribute2;
```

Example for the above header:

```
;John;Doe;
```

---

Complete Impex script looks like this:

```
INSERT Address ; firstname ; lastname ;
               ; John      ; Doe      ;
```

---

**Complex data types**

When an attribute type is not a primitive (string, integer...) but a complex type you need to define attributes that identify the value you want to set to your attribute. AN EXAMPLE: If you want to create a price, you will need a currency for the price. Currency is an own itemtype, so you need to identify the currency by an attribute of the itemtype currency. Currency has a unique attribute called "isocode". So you use the isocode of the currency to identify which currency should be used.

**EXAMPLE**

```
INSERT PriceRow;...; currency(isocode);
               ;   ; USD              ;
```

Using paranthesis you can add an attribute or a comma separated list of attributes to an attribute in your header. If you need multiple attributes to identify the target value, the values of these attributes are separed by colons. You can also nest those expressions as in your example:

```
insert TaxRow ; ... ; catalogVersion(catalog(id),version) ;
              ;     ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged         ;
```

The values for attribute catalogVersion of type TaxRow are identified by the attributes catalog and version of the target type CatalogVersion. The two are separated by a comma. A catalog however is a complex type (again) and is identified by its id attribute. The two values that identify your item of type CatalogVersion are "hybrisProductCatalog" and "Staged". So the script searches a CatalogVersion item, that has a Catalog assigned with the id hybrisProductCatalog and a version Staged.

These values need to identify **EXACTLY ONE** item. Otherwise your script will fail.

---

**Unique values**

When using INSERT_UPDATE, UPDATE or REMOVE, you need to identify the items you want to change. You do that by adding attribute to the header that uniquely identify the item you want to change. You do that by adding [unique=true] to the attribute. As in your example:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Product ; code[unique=true] ; catalogVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true] ;
                      ; BP_101628163      ; hybrisProductCatalog:Staged ;
```

In this case you either insert a new product with the code BP_101628163 and the catalogVersion hybrisProductCatalog:Staged or you change an existing one that has these values.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination. I thinks in my case everything is according to you explanation but still I don't understand why the script is not working and the real problem is that it's not telling at which part the exact issue is.

Comment: There are so much pitfalls. And you can see that there are so many attributes that are changed. I cannot search every attribute for an error. For every attribute there are different conditions that might raise an error. Also often there is a more detailed log error message before the impex log message is shown. There are also cases where there is no detailed message, but that cases are very hard to debug.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case there is no detailed message in a log.

Comment: @JohannesNolte Hello, please may I ask? I have an Order, so I do INSERT Order;.. (but here I want to put an object "Product"). How should it look like? Thanks it means a lot for me.

Comment: You want to add an entry to the order. Try INSERT OrderEntry;order(code);product(code,catalogVersion);...